# No methods of component getting called when coming back to it (react-native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm using `react-native (version: 0.52.2)` along with `redux` and `react-navigation(version: 1.5.6)`. I've 2 screens as A and B. When I navigate from A to B and then come back to A again, where should I handle any events (like api call or state change) in A?
I expected any lifecycle method of A to get called when coming back to A but nothing is being called by react-native.